# Chaindata behind in blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, blockchain

My Mist wallet shows Im synced but when I go to the chaindata folder it is about 130000 behind.Does anyone know why this is. I do not seem to have a problem with geth or mist but curious why the chaindata is so far behind.

Comment: Is the chaindata folder changing? (i.e. Is it being populated, regardless of what Mist is telling you?) Are you looking at the correct chaindata? (i.e. Have you previously used the testnet, etc.?)

Comment: I've never used testnet. And my first number was wrong, its a 1,1000,000 behind. Mist wallet is showing all blocks synced(except when new blocks are created). And yes I can watch the chaindata being populated while mist is populating but I believe when mist stops so does the chaindata population.